# Trying to delete files through power shell based on CSV column input

Tags: powershell

I am trying to delete files using PowerShell script and taking files in put details from CSV file.

CSV File-

[image]

Below is PowerShell code.

```
$files = Get-Content "C:\DeleteFiles\FilesPresent1.csv"
foreach ($file in $files) {
    Remove-Item -Path $file.ServerRelativeUrl.Trim() -Force
}

Write-Host -foregroundcolor yellow "Delete action complete"
```

But still i am not able achieve this, can any one suggest me what exactly i am doing wrong here, Guide me with right direction.

Comment: Use `Import-Csv` instead of `Get-Content` and your code should work fine with that change. Also might be worth recommending using `Remove-Item -LiteralPath` instead of `Remove-Item -Path` in this case

Comment: ok let me try it quickly

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon it's working fine, i am new to PowerShell is there any trick if we check file is exist or not in location if its exist then will delete it because if we put any file in csv which is not exist that  in csv that throwing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as you have it right now would work by only changing `Get-Content` (meant to read plain text unstructured data) to [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.3) (meant for reading Csvs as its name implies). For testing if the paths exist you can use [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-7.3):

```bash
Import-Csv "C:\DeleteFiles\FilesPresent1.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Checking on '$($_.ServerRelativeUrl)'..."
    # Check if the file exists
    if (Test-Path $_.ServerRelativeUrl) {
        # If it does, delete it
        Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_.ServerRelativeUrl.Trim() -Force
        Write-Host "Deleted: '$($_.ServerRelativeUrl)'..."
        # And go to the next file
        return
    }

    # If it doesn't exist
    Write-Host "'$($_.ServerRelativeUrl)' couldn't be found, skipping..."
}

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Delete action complete"
```